# Why can't we iterate over the keys of an Event object?

Tags: javascript

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hill-6kmhq) is a codesandbox for this question.

I have an html document, and the body has one `div` with id `container`. There is a script tag with source in `index.js`. In the latter, I get the div by id, and add an event listener for the click event. In the handler I take Object.keys on the event object, and console.log the keys. I only get one key logged out, the first one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">hello</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// index.js

const div = document.getElementById("container");

div.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(event) {
    console.log("Clicked div, bubbling phase", event);
    Object.keys(event).forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item);
    });
  },
  false
);
```

**The result of clicking the div is**

[image]

**What's up with this?** Why can't I see all the keys?

Comment: They might be inherited or non-enumerable…

Comment: @kaiido your link does not answer my question. FYI, the code I am using is straight from a book called "DOM Enlightened". What does this have to do with an Error object?

Comment: errors show the same behaviour as your events, and the link explains what this is